# jQuery Flot data/axis labels on top of graph

Tags: jquery, label, flot, graphing

Is there a way to overlay the x-axis and y-axis numeric labels onto a jQuery Flot graph. So, I want the labels to not be outside, next to the graph, but on top of the graph itself.

The following example creates an overlay div on top of the graph for the annotations:
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/annotating.html

Is there a straightforward way of grabbing the text and formatting of an axis from within flot and creating such an overlay out of it? Or, is there maybe another better way of overlaying the axis labels on top of the graph?

Comment: Is my answer not satisfying/working? Please provide feedback

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way, which isn't particularly clean and especially won't work nicely if you plan to show x- and y-axis tick labels at the same time, is to set the `labelMargin` option on the `grid` to a negative value.

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, {
    ...
    grid: { ..., labelMargin: -20, ... }
    ...
});
```

---

A second idea could be to grab all `div`'s which have `class="tickLabel"` after the graph has been painted. And then "manually" alter their CSS positioning.

```
$("div.tickLabel").each(function(i,ele) {
    ele = $(ele);
    if (ele.css("text-align") == "center") { //x-axis
        ele.css("top", ele.position().top - 20); //move them up over graph
    } else {  //y-axis
        ele.css("left", ele.position().left + 20); //move them right over graph
    }
});
```

Of course this still has some issues as the lowest tick label values on the x- and y-axis will overlap each other and the lowest/highest tick label values on the x- and y-axis will be positioned on the edges of the graph. But with some fine-tuning this might be a viable solution.

---

A third idea would be to directly use a `tickFormatter` for the tick labels of the x- and y-axis. This works similar to the second idea but would place them directly where you want them to be without the maybe noticeable "label flickering" on repositioning which may occur with the function in the second idea.

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, {
    ...
    xaxis: {
        ...,
        tickFormatter: function formatter(val, axis) {
           //return appropriately absolute positioned element
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

How this `tickFormatter` function could look like is best derived by looking at the [jQuery Flot sourcecode](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js) especially the function `measureLabels` (this gets you an idea how Flot itself positions the tick labels) and the default tick formatter which looks like

```
function (v, axis) {
    return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals);
};
```