# How do I put tick labels inside of a line graph in Flot

Tags: flot, label

I essentially want to have the tick labels sitting inside the graph in their own column. Similar to how Campaign Monitor graphs are. But I can't find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of flot, the only thing you can control about the ticks is the contents and the label class (all ticks have the class "tickLabel").

I think with those two abilities, you **cannot** do what you're looking for.

Check out this flot bug for some code modifications that might get you to what you want:  http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=191

Answer (score 0):

How is this question different than this one?

[jQuery Flot data/axis labels on top of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836980/jquery-flot-data-axis-labels-on-top-of-graph)

For that one, someone suggests negative labelMargins